# JDBC connection to Oracle Cloud ATP 19c

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm using Java 8 and trying to test JDBC connection to a new Oracle Cloud Database from NetBeans 8.2

```java
package project;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;

public class UCPSample {
  //final static String DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521/orclservicename";
  // Use the TNS Alias name along with the TNS_ADMIN - For ATP and ADW
  final static String DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@almubarak_medium?TNS_ADMIN=/src/Wallet_almubarak/";

  final static String DB_USER = "Admin";
  final static String DB_PASSWORD = "mypassword";
  final static String CONN_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource";

  /*
   * The sample demonstrates UCP as client side connection pool.
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // Get the PoolDataSource for UCP
    PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

    // Set the connection factory first before all other properties
    pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName(CONN_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME);
    pds.setURL(DB_URL);
    pds.setUser(DB_USER);
    pds.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
    pds.setConnectionPoolName("JDBC_UCP_POOL");

    // Default is 0. Set the initial number of connections to be created
    // when UCP is started.
    pds.setInitialPoolSize(5);

    // Default is 0. Set the minimum number of connections
    // that is maintained by UCP at runtime.
    pds.setMinPoolSize(5);

    // Default is Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647). Set the maximum number of
    // connections allowed on the connection pool.
    pds.setMaxPoolSize(20);

    // Default is 30secs. Set the frequency in seconds to enforce the timeout
    // properties. Applies to inactiveConnectionTimeout(int secs),
    // AbandonedConnectionTimeout(secs)& TimeToLiveConnectionTimeout(int secs).
    // Range of valid values is 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE. .
    pds.setTimeoutCheckInterval(5);

    // Default is 0. Set the maximum time, in seconds, that a
    // connection remains available in the connection pool.
    pds.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(10);

    // Get the database connection from UCP.
    try (Connection conn = pds.getConnection()) {
      System.out.println("Available connections after checkout: "
          + pds.getAvailableConnectionsCount());
      System.out.println("Borrowed connections after checkout: "
          + pds.getBorrowedConnectionsCount());
      // Perform a database operation
      doSQLWork(conn);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("UCPSample - " + "SQLException occurred : "
          + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Available connections after checkin: "
        + pds.getAvailableConnectionsCount());
    System.out.println("Borrowed connections after checkin: "
        + pds.getBorrowedConnectionsCount());
  }

  /*
   * Creates an EMP table and does an insert, update and select operations on
   * the new table created.
   */
  public static void doSQLWork(Connection conn) {
    try {
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);
      // Prepare a statement to execute the SQL Queries.
      Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
      // Create table EMP
      statement.executeUpdate("create table EMP(EMPLOYEEID NUMBER,"
          + "EMPLOYEENAME VARCHAR2 (20))");
      System.out.println("New table EMP is created");
      // Insert some records into the table EMP
      statement.executeUpdate("insert into EMP values(1, 'Jennifer Jones')");
      statement.executeUpdate("insert into EMP values(2, 'Alex Debouir')");
      System.out.println("Two records are inserted.");

      // Update a record on EMP table.
      statement.executeUpdate("update EMP set EMPLOYEENAME='Alex Deborie'"
          + " where EMPLOYEEID=2");
      System.out.println("One record is updated.");

      // Verify the table EMP
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from EMP");
      System.out.println("\nNew table EMP contains:");
      System.out.println("EMPLOYEEID" + " " + "EMPLOYEENAME");
      System.out.println("--------------------------");
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2));
      }
      System.out.println("\nSuccessfully tested a connection from UCP");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("UCPSample - "
          + "doSQLWork()- SQLException occurred : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
      // Clean-up after everything
      try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
        statement.execute("drop table EMP");
      }
      catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("UCPSample - "
            + "doSQLWork()- SQLException occurred : " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the documentation [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/java-connectivity-to-atp.html)

1. download my wallet folder to src folder
2. download and install  JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.
3. download and add all ojdbc8-full jars files to my library

I always get error message

```
UCPSample - SQLException occurred : Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Cannot get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Comment: tried TNS_ADMIN=
- /src/Wallet_almubarak/
- /src/Wallet_almubarak
- src/Wallet_almubarak/
- /Wallet_almubarak/
- /Wallet_almubarak

Comment: The TNS_ADMIN should be the full path to the unzipped directory. Did you modify the sqlnet.ora or ojdbc.properties files as explained in the page you pointed to?

Comment: thanx for reply 
no changes needed for both files when using wallet
and i tried before to put the full path  but with the same  error as an output

Comment: change to 
'final static String DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@almubarak_medium?TNS_ADMIN=C:\\Users\\Taher\\Downloads\\Wallet_almubarak";' 
error changed to
'Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 70'

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure the path that you are giving is the absolute path for the wallet location? Also, what is the OS? If you are using Windows use its file separators. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

it works finally when i separate the TNS_ADMIN as CONNECTION_PROPERTY not in the Connection string

```
Properties info = new Properties();     
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_USER_NAME, DB_USER);
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_PASSWORD, DB_PASSWORD);          
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_DEFAULT_ROW_PREFETCH, "20");    
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_TNS_ADMIN,"c:\\Wallet_almubarak");
```